# java nested class with static initializer

Tags: java, static, initialization

Was reading the book called Emergent Design and on the topic of singleton ...

```
public class MyApp {
 private class SingletonHolder {
  public Object singleton; 
  static {
   singleton = new Object(); 
  }
 }
}
```

then eclipse keeps complaining about the static {}

Was reading Java, classes supposed to be able to have multi static initializer. So how can I make the above work ?

---

```
/tmp/jc_4873/MyApp.java:5: non-static variable singleton cannot be referenced from a static context
   singleton = new Object(); 
   ^
/tmp/jc_4873/MyApp.java:4: inner classes cannot have static declarations
  static {
  ^
2 errors
```

---

```
public class MyApp {
 private class SingletonHolder {
  public static Object singleton; 
  static {
   singleton = new Object(); 
  }
 }
}

/tmp/jc_8488/MyApp.java:3: inner classes cannot have static declarations
  public static Object singleton; 
                       ^
/tmp/jc_8488/MyApp.java:4: inner classes cannot have static declarations
  static {
  ^
2 errors
```

---

```
public class MyApp {
 private static class SingletonHolder {
  public static Object singleton; 
  static {
   singleton = new Object(); 
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a field to be legally referenced in a static context, the field must either be local to the context or declared as static within the class.  If you want to reference `singleton`, you will need to declare it `static`.

Comment: +1 agree and I'll also add that SingletonHolder should probably be a static class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `private static Object singleton;` Static block cannot modify a non static variable.